# Inner div's children to expand horizontally

Tags: html, css

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YFx65/1/)

I want the inner blue divs to be placed horizontally, side by side, instead of gridded. I've tried using `white-space:nowrap` but it does not work because these are block elements.

If I set a fixed width to the `#subcontainer` layer it works, but I don't know the width of that layer as it gets dynamically rendered using server data.

I cannot use `display: inline-block` because the layers need to be together, with no gap between them.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a large percentage width on #subcontainer

http://jsfiddle.net/YFx65/5/